# Steema TeeChart: We have a licensing problem in Xamarin.Forms Droid

Tags: android, xamarin, teechart

We are developing a Xamarin.Forms app on MacOS Monterey 12.3.1 (21E258). We are using the Steema Chart since a long time and never had troubles with it. We now encounter a problem with the licensing in the Android application.

Whatever we try, we can not remove the watermark in the release build. :(

We created the TeeChart.licenses file on a Windows 10 (10.0.19043.1645) and included it in de project as mentioned in the help. This has always worked perfect for years, but since recently we run into this problem.

We are using this version of the nuget package Steema.TeeChart.NET.Xamarin.Forms => 4.2022.2.28

I hope someone has a solution for this, because we really need to push a new version of our apps.

We are using Visual Studio for Mac 2019 8.10.22 with following components

Mono Framework MDK
Runtime:
Mono 6.12.0.174 (2020-02/adf1bc4335d) (64-bit)
Package version: 612000174

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 13.3.1 (20103)

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 15.8.0.3 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: eb7f8ed35
Branch: xcode13.3
Build date: 2022-03-30 03:16:09-0400

Xamarin.Android
Version: 12.2.4.3 (Visual Studio Community)
Commit: xamarin-android/d17-1/fc1125e

Comment: if you are having a licensing problem with a library that you **have paid for** then contacting the support for the library seems like the best way to fix it

Comment: Thanks @Jason for your advice but that is not really helping.  We have asked for support and Steema support is lookign at it. I'm posting it here also to find other people with the same problem and maybe to help the community it we find a solution. I have posted the same question on the forum of Steema.